# Pearson correlation metric for Tensorflow 2 Keras

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, pearson-correlation

I have a model which have for each sample 8 outputs. I would like to compute for each sample pearson correlation and then compute the mean of the pearsons values of the samples. I would like then to insert it as a metric to the model. Now I have this function:

```
def tf_pearson(x, y):    
    mx = tf.math.reduce_mean(input_tensor=x)
    my = tf.math.reduce_mean(input_tensor=y)
    xm, ym = x-mx, y-my
    r_num = tf.math.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.multiply(xm,ym))        
    r_den = tf.math.reduce_std(xm) * tf.math.reduce_std(ym)
    return  r_num / r_den
```

which, I think, should calculate the pearson to all the samples at once.

I wanted to do something like this:

```
def tf_pearson(x, y):
    print(x.shape)
    print(y.shape)    
    mx = tf.math.reduce_mean(input_tensor=x, axis=1)
    my = tf.math.reduce_mean(input_tensor=y, axis=1)
    print(mx.shape)
    print(my.shape)  
    xm, ym = x-mx, y-my
    r_num = tf.math.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.multiply(xm,ym), axis=1)        
    r_den = tf.math.reduce_std(xm, axis=1) * tf.math.reduce_std(ym, axis=1)
    return   tf.math.reduce_mean(input_tensor=r_num / r_den)
```

But since the tensor first dimension shape is None, reduce_mean always reduce.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `"reduce_mean always reduce"` but you can call it with `keepdims=True` if you want to keep the shape.

Comment: I think he means, that is does not keep batch dimension.